# Unable to import Pandas and Seaborn (in Anaconda/Spyder)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, anaconda, spyder, seaborn

I recently installed the Seaborn library (its dependent packages were auto updated). Everything  was working fine,  but suddenly I'm unable to import neither Seaborn nor Pandas.

I'm getting this error below:

> import pandas as pd
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > File "< stdin>",  line 1, in < module>
> >
> > File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 13, in < module>
> >         "extensions first.".format(module))
> >
> > ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.

Comment: Please tell us the exact commands you used to install `seaborn`. Without that information your question cannot be answered properly.

Comment: @cel I used `conda install seaborn` from Anaconda command line.

Comment: What happens if you do `conda remove pandas`, `pip uninstall pandas` `conda install pandas`?

Comment: @cel Great, this worked! Now that my `pandas` is working, I tried to install `seaborn` using `conda install seaborn` again, and now they both are working fine. Thank you!
Does `pip uninstall pandas` make a cleaner uninstall than `conda remove pandas`? Or there's a different reason for using it?

Comment: conda's binary packaged should always work after installing, because there's no compilation phase that can go wrong. If you use pip, you have more sources of errors. The error you showed seemed like somehow `pandas` was installed or updated by `pip`. That's why I suggested to remove it completely and then install conda's version afterwards.

Comment: @cel thanks for your suggestion but  I am facing the same issue but ur suggestion is unable to solve my probelm :( even after uninstalling pandas and reinstalling it , now I am able to import pandas in ipython notebook but not in Python GUI IDE :( and seaborn is not working anywhere